# f seems to be always positive in the MATLAB code, but in my Python code, f also gets negative values

Tags: python, matlab, matrix, eigenvector

How to convert the [following MATLAB](http://pastebin.com/fZe0AZQn) code to Python? [Here is my solution](http://pastebin.com/gFcr8HGR), but it doesn't quite produce the same results. For example, `f` seems to be always positive in the MATLAB code, but in my Python code, `f` also gets negative values.

Any ideas how to fix the program?

Mostly, I am concerned about these:
MATLAB:

```
    for k = 1 : nx  
            j = k+2;
```

Python:

```
for k in range(1,nx+1):  
    j = k+2
```

MATLAB:

```
    [V,D] = eig(A, B);  
    DD = diag(D);  
    keep_idxs = find( ~isinf(DD) );  
    D = diag( DD(keep_idxs) );  
    V = V(:, keep_idxs);  
    [lambda, idx] = min(diag(D));  
    f = V(:,idx);
```

Python:

```
w,vr = scipy.linalg.decomp.eig(A,B)  
w = w.real  
vr = vr.real  
w = w[2:-1-2]  
lambda_ = w.min()  
idx = w.argmin()  
f = vr[:,idx]
```

MATLAB:

```
    f = f(3:end-2);  
    [nf, nf_idx] = max(abs(f)); % L_infty norm  
    n2 = f(nf_idx); % normalize sign away, too  
    f = f ./ n2;
```

Python:

```
f = f[2:-1-1]  
nf = max(np.absolute(f))  
nf_idx = np.absolute(f).argmax()  
nf_idx = np.ma.argmax(f)  
n2 = f[nf_idx]  
f = f/n2
```

MATLAB:

```
    xx = -kappa:h:kappa;
```

Python:

```
xx = np.arange(-kappa, kappa+h, h)
```

Are those equivalent with each other? If they are, then why don't they produce exact the same results?

Comment: You need to format your code correctly, and be more specific about your problem. What are you talking about?

Comment: The syntax is quite different. In MATLAB indices start from 1, in Python they start from 0. I want to know if I have made any errors that will produce different results.

Comment: I try to solve numerically an eigenvalue problem. The code is in MATLAB and I try to convert it to Python.

Comment: Please post an actual example where the results differ. Also note that eigenvectors are not unique, and if the eigenvalues are degenerate, different choices for the eigenvectors can be made, so there is no "correct" choice for the eigenvectors. If Matlab and Scipy use different algorithms for the eigendecomposition, then the results can be completely different.

Comment: This is the Figure 1 from the MATLAB: http://img834.imageshack.us/i/27246498.png/

This is the Figure 1 from the Python: http://img340.imageshack.us/i/figure1c.png/

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about matlab, but for python the code

```
for k in range(1,nx+1):  
  j = k+2
```

is the same as

```
j = nx+2
```

This isn't your main problem, but it's worrying.

Comment: Yes, I think that in MATLAB the last value in the loop that will be calculated is, too, j = nx+2.